# Scrape elements inside tag properties - Scrapy

Tags: python, tags, web-scraping, scrapy, embed

I am using Scrapy to scrape a video site. I am having a little difficulty to scrape some things.

Ex.

```
<embed width="588" height="476" flashvars="id_video=7845976&amp;theskin=default&amp;url_bigthumb=http://sample.com/image.jpg&amp;key=4219e347d8fdc0be3103eb3cbb458258-1416371743&amp;categories=cat1" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" src="http://static.sample.com/swf/xv-player.swf" wmode="transparent" id="flash-player-embed" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

I am currently able to scrape the properties of html tags using the statement below :-

```
item['thumb'] = hxs.select("//embed[@id='flash-player-embed']/@flashvars").extract()[0]
```

The above statement gives the below result :-

> id_video=7845976&theskin=default&url_bigthumb=http://sample.com/image.jpg&key=4219e347d8fdc0be3103eb3cbb458258-1416371743&categories=cat1"
>   allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high"
>   src="http://static.sample.com/swf/xv-player.swf

I want a hxs.select statement such that it could extract only the image url from the above embedded code like this :-

> http://sample.com/image.jpg

I have tried :-

```
item['thumb'] = hxs.select("//embed[@id='flash-player-embed']/@flashvars/@url_bigthumb").extract()[0]
```

but it's of no use as it is not working.

Any help from the Scrapy or the Python committee is very much appreciated as it will save my precious Megabits.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is you can use split function to obtain your exact result.

For example,

```
hxs.select('//embed[@id='flash-player-embed']/@flashvars').extract()[0].split('url_bigthumb=')[1].split('key')[0].replace('&amp;','').strip().replace('&','').strip()
```

This is the simplest way you can use as of now, but you can wait for the good answers.

Thanks

Comment: Thank You... Your solution worked. I had to modify it a bit. But let me know if this will give me the fastest crawl rate or shall I try somethings from the other answers mentioned here.

Comment: Actually, you can use this way for the time being, For concurrent use of your script try the answer by ( Nima Soroush ) using urlparse. I also tried that, it was working good.

Answer (score 2):

[urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) also provide a nice solution for getting elements:

```
>>from urlparse import parse_qs, urlparse
>>url = '?' + 'id_video=7845976&theskin=default&url_bigthumb=http://sample.com/image.jpg&key=4219e347d8fdc0be3103eb3cbb458258-1416371743&categories=cat1" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" src="http://static.sample.com/swf/xv-player.swf'

>>print parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['url_bigthumb']
['http://sample.com/image.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution using regex would be:

```
re.findall(r'http?://[^\s<>&"]+|www\.[^\s<>&"]+', item['thumb'])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression after the XPath selection with the .re() method:

```
>>> sel = Selector(text="""<embed width="588" height="476" flashvars="id_video=7845976&amp;theskin=default&amp;url_bigthumb=http://sample.com/image.jpg&amp;key=4219e347d8fdc0be3103eb3cbb458258-1416371743&amp;categories=cat1" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" src="http://static.sample.com/swf/xv-player.swf" wmode="transparent" id="flash-player-embed" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">""")
>>> sel.xpath("//embed/@flashvars").re('url_bigthumb=([^&]+)')
[u'http://sample.com/image.jpg']
```

#### Read more:

- [Using selectors with regular expressions - Scrapy Docs](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions)